# Why $m(E\backslash E_x)\leq m(E\backslash E')+m(E'\backslash E'_x)+m(E'_x\backslash E_x)\leq ...$

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let denote $E_x=E+x$. I have to prove that $$\lim_{x\to 0}m(E\backslash  E_x)=0$$
for $E\subset \mathbb R$ measurable s.t. $m(E)<\infty $. I know that there exist $E'=\bigcup_{i=1}^N Q_i$ where the $Q_i$ are closed interval such that 
$$m(E\Delta E')\leq \varepsilon$$
for all $x$ and thus 
$$m(E_x\Delta E'_x)\leq \varepsilon$$
for all $x$. My teacher wrote:

Then we have that
$$m(E\backslash E_x)\leq m(E\backslash E')+m(E'\backslash E'_x)+m(E'_x\backslash E_x)\leq ...$$

And I don't understand where it comes from, do we have that for all set $A,B,C,D$ that 
$$A\backslash D\subset (A\backslash B)\cup (B\backslash C)\cup (C\backslash D)\ \ ?$$

Comment: no body can answer ?